# Not understanding how the NavigationController and UIViewControllers are working in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a project which I don't really understand the views and navigation behind. I start out in the `AppDelegate` (`MAAppDelegate`), where I define properties:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *detailViewController;
```

Then in the `MAAppDelegate.m`, I create a `navigationController`, and

```
@implementation MAAppDelegate
@synthesize detailViewController;
@synthesize window;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    // Init the navController for the Master Detail View of the grade cells

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];


    detailViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    UIViewController *viewController = [[MAController alloc] init];

    navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];

    self.window.rootViewController = viewController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

So at this point, I think I have a working `naviationController`, I've setup an instance of a custom `UIViewController` (custom class `MAController`) and I've set it up as the `rootViewController`.

Then, in my `MAController` class, the class where I do **all** of my UI stuff (the entire UI is done programmatically, no nibs or storyboards). Here is a bit of the `viewDidLoad` of `MAController`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES]; // I commented this line out and realized it does nothing
```

I go on (in `viewDidLoad`) to add a bunch of subviews to `self.view`, like this

```
[self.view addSubview:self.backgroundImageView];
```

Earlier, I created a `viewController` in the `AppDelegate` class and it was called `view`, so I assumed it was refereeing to that but now since I've changed it (in `AppDelegate`) to `viewController`, I guess I was thinking wrong?

And then finally, I create a `UIView` in 'viewDidLoad`:

```
UIView *header = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:headerFrame];
header.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = header;
```

and start adding a bunch of subviews to this new UIView I created `header`.

So, in short, I have *no idea* what is happening. Later, when I tried telling (from a method inside `MAController`) `self.navigationController` (which I assumed to be `navigationController` in charge of everything in my project - created at the beginning in the `AppDelegate`) to `pushViewController` a new `viewController` that I was going to use as a detailView for a table, it got weird.

So I'm just trying to understand what has control, and what the `rootViewController` is, and just what is happening.

Comment: the `rootViewController` is just that - the starting (or initial) view controller in your app.  Your first problem is that you have set `viewController` as both the initial view controller for your navigationController and as your app's root view controller.  You should set self.window.rootViewController=navController.  Alternatively use storyboards - It can be a bit of a 'religious' thing between those that use IB and those that prefer programmatically creating everything, but I find storyboards much faster

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by "it got weird".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main window root is set to a view controller and not the navigation controller

Change:

```
self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
```

to:

```
self.window.rootViewController = navController;
```

EDIT:

You can access the navigationController from anywhere by asking your appDelegate. It is normally not considered a good practice:

```
MAAppDelegate *delegate = (MAAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
UINavigationController *nav = delegate.navigationController;
```

Don't forget to:

```
#import "MAAppDelegate.h"
```

Comment: How do I access the `navController` I create in `MAAppDelegate` in the `MAController` class? Is is just `self.navController`?

Comment: It is normally not a good practice, but you can get the navigationController by asking your application delegate:    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    UINavigationController *nav = delegate.navigationController;

Answer (score 1):

First, take a little time and read through how navigation controllers work. The documentation is really helpful:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Second, your problem is that your window's root view controller is not the navigation controller you created. Rather it is an instance of `MAController`. This is what you're doing:

```
UIViewController *viewController = [[MAController alloc] init];

// some other code ...

self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
```

I think you meant to add `MAController` as the root view controller of the navigation controller  and make the navigation controller your window's root. If so, you'll want to set your view controllers up like this:

```
UIViewController *viewController = [[MAController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
self.window.rootViewController = navController;
```

Another potential problem is that you don't seem to be doing anything with your `detailViewController`. Maybe that's confusing you too.

Comment: I'm going to go through the documentation tomorrow, thank you, the `detailViewControl` I use for a master-detail type `TableView` with the `detailViewControl` the `UIView` for the detail of some of the table cells.

Comment: How do I access the `navController` I create in `MAAppDelegate` in the `MAController` class? Is is just `self.navController`?

Comment: Yes, in this case, that's how you would access MAController's navigation controller.